# Is it possible to use savepoint and rollback in Oracle express edition?

Tags: database, oracle

I'm using Oracle express edition. Whenever I use the savepoint statement, I get an invalid statement error. Is it not valid in Oracle express edition. I'm using the latest version. I also faced the same problem when I was using the desktops in my university. I don't know what's wrong with it. I'll be so happy with your help. Many thanks.

Edit:

My code:

```
savepoint s;
```

The error that I'm getting

```
ORA-00911: invalid character
```

Comment: I've also unchecked the auto commit check box. Still not helpful.

Comment: Can you add the exact statement that you are using and the exact error message that you get?

Comment: Oracle database XE has obviously rollback capabilities :)

Comment: Please provide the detailed steps that cause you this issue.

Comment: @loic actually I'm getting an invalid character error when I'm creating a savepoint itself

Comment: @Simon I've edited the question. I'm getting an invalid character error when i'm creating a savepoint. I used the following syntax: savepoint savepoint_name;

Comment: @loic Can you please help me? Is my syntax wrong? savepoint savepoint_name;

Comment: are you using it inside a PL/SQL block?

Comment: Is your savepoint ACTUALLY called "savepoint_name"? As you can see in the answer below, you might be using an invalid name for the savepoint.

Comment: Its impossible to debug code that you cannot see.  Please update your original to show (copy and paste) the exact commands and exact responses.

Comment: @loic I'm not using it in PL/SQL block.

Comment: @Simon No Simon. The name of my savepoint is s[savepoint s; ]

Comment: @EdStevens I've edited my question. Can you get my point now?

Comment: A single line of code, taken out of context, is little better than no code at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ROLLBACK to SAVEPOINT is supported by the free Oracle Database Express Edition.
Tested with the 18c release: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/xe.html

Limitations of this version are listed here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/xelic/licensing-information.html#GUID-0F2574A6-360F-4237-8098-17B02FFC3BB3

Your error "00911: invalid character" is related to the way you invoke the "SAVEPOINT S;" command...

For instance in Java, you would need to get rid of the ";" character to make it work:

```
 [...]
 Statement s = c.createStatement();
 ResultSet r = s.execute( "SAVEPOINT S" ); // "SAVEPOINT S;" will produce ORA-00911
 [...]
```

Comment: Thank You loic. I'm using Application Express 2.1.0.00.39 . I think this is a old version. Thank you so much for your time. Many Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer the *title* question: yes.

```
SQL> select * From v$version;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.2.0      Production
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production

SQL> savepoint a;

Savepoint created.

SQL> delete from emp;

14 rows deleted.

SQL> rollback to a;

Rollback complete.

SQL>
```

Comment: I've did the same thing just like you did. But when I run the savepint a; statement, I get an error as "ORA-00911: invalid character"

Comment: Which tool do you use?

Comment: Oracle Database Express Edition

Comment: which tool do you use to connect and run SQL commands? sqlplus, SQL Developer, other?

Comment: @loic I think I have a long way to go. I haven't even heard about that before. I installed the Oracle database express edition. And then I used to go to the database homepage, open SQL commands and start executing my commands over there.